# What are the names of these coding styles?

Tags: c, coding-style

I am trying to explain different coding styles to some individuals I am training.  The only issue is, I don't know the semantic name for these 2 styles of programming.

For example, I know that this is GNU:

```
class Object
{
    // statements
}
```

I need help defining these two:

```
class Object {

}
```

and this variable naming style:

```
string sNotHungarianNotation = "";
string but_this_style        = "";
```

where the variables have underscores between them.

I'd appreciate the help.  I've looked at several different sources but could not come to a cogent answer.

Comment: First one isn't GNU: it's Allman. Second is K&R.

Comment: `this_this_snake_case`

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for these philosophical programming questions

Comment: As to coding styles - chose your poison and kept to it!

Comment: @EdHeal choose, not chose :P, not to be a grammar police but I couldn't pass that one up

Comment: welp, this was a simple question.  Thanks guys.   My google-fu did not prevail tonight...

Comment: @JoshEngelsma - Try explaining that to my company and you are a better man than me.

Comment: also I find the K&R very interesting.. they put the opening brace on the next line for function definitions, and anything in, will be on the same line..  iiiinteresting.  Also, @Almo, someone should let ProCSSor know (thats where I got the GNU name from for that style)

Comment: K&R is an evil holdover from tiny monitors. That's my opinion anyway. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as names for brace positioning, if you really care about them, [Indent style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) on Wikipedia has far more info than you'll probably ever care about. That said, your two examples are typically referred to as Allman style and K&R style, respectively.

For variable naming, your first example is typically called `camelCase` and the second version is often referred to as `snake_case`.

Comment: i'm familiar with camelCase, and it's hungarian notation with camel casing.  and what the heck - why wasn't that page obvious to me?  I looked at all kinds of wiki pages describing different kinds but it didn't list the name.

Comment: "As far as names for brace positioning" - s**t this plane is crashing and I am going to be found in the wreckage by my loved ones kissing my bottom